# Efficient way to save data

Tags: python

In my simulation program, I calculate about 50 numbers in one step, and repeat this step about 100000 times. I need to save all these numbers for plotting them.

I use python,and I thought two ways.

1. do all calculation at once by appending these numbers to list  or
2. for each step, write 50 numbers in file, and repeat this.

I actually made this program by using the first way, such as

```
for i in range(100000):
    data.append(calculated numbers)
```

but I think this is too memory wasting.
but I also think that the second way is slower than first(?).

In this case, what can be efficient way?

Comment: So this is not a question about efficiency of the serialized data (small saved data footprint), right?

Comment: Also 50*100000*size(int) doesn't seem to be that much memory. I'd just go with the easiest to read and maintain as long as the numbers aren't that high.

Comment: The numbers varies by control parameters by user input, and I am expecting the number 50*100000 can be vary about 20 times greater or less. so I'm just worrying about memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to compute the numbers in batches and write them to disk as you go.  Depending on the file system you are using, you will want to write larger than a certain chunk size to avoid excessive disk writes.  Your performance hit in method 2 should be because you are triggering 100000 disk writes.  Instead, write to the disk after every 1000 cycles.  Then you only have 100 disk writes, but you only use about 50,000 numbers of memory at a time.  Then you have high performance and stay within your RAM limit.

Also, consider using xrange instead of range so you aren't allocating a list of 100000 numbers just to do the loop.

Comment: Your advise about xrange is good but only if the OP is using Python 2.x.  Python 3 makes range iterable rather than a list builder.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NumPy to store the numbers in an array (with dimensions `(50, 100000)` in your example).  If you need to store them, NumPy has `save()` and `load()` functions which use an efficient binary format.

Comment: This would mean a lock-in depending on the binary format of NumPy. I think OP should clarify the requirement. As-is this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: If you don't like NumPy's binary format, you can use HDF5 which is truly cross-platform and language agnostic.  Or CSV if you don't care about efficiency much.

Comment: I wanted to say that OP wants to use it later to plot things and didn't specify the program. So I assume it must be something simple like the gnuplot space separated format or CSV.

Answer (score 1):

One way to minimize memory is You can use `xrange` instead or `range` to minimize memory uses.